# Who was the Shishya of Rishi Pulatsya, sent a message to his grandson, Ravana through Vibhishana?

Tags: ramayana, ramcharitmanas, vibhishana

When Ravana got the news of Lord Rama's arriving at the opposite side of sea along with Vanarasena ready to fight with Ravana, Ravana asked his councillors "Give me proper advice." His councillors advised  nothing to bother as when we conquered the Devas and Asuras with no difficulty then of what accounts, can men and monkeys be!

That a time, finding an opportunity, Vibhishana arrived at council to provide his opinion which is to give up the enmity with Sri Rama and restore Sita to Rama as Rama is not a human king but he is Lord of the universe.

According to Ramacharitamanas (Ramayana authored by Sant Tulasidasa), after explaining Ravana by many ways, at last Vibhishana spoken as follows:

Quoting from [Ramacharitmanas > Sunder Kanda > Verse 39](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n801/mode/2up?view=theater)

> > बार बार पद लागउँ बिनय करउँ दससीस।
> > परिहरि मान मोह मद भजहु कोसलाधीस।।39(क)।।
> > **मुनि पुलस्ति निज सिष्य सन कहि पठई यह बात।**
> > तुरत सो मैं प्रभु सन कही पाइ सुअवसरु तात।।39(ख)।।
>
> Again and again I fall at your feet and pray you, Ravana: abandoning pride, infatuation and arrogance, adore the Lord of Kosala. **The sage Pulastya (our grandfather) had sent this message to us through a disciple of his.** Availing myself of this golden opportunity, dear brother, I have immediately conveyed it to you.

So, Who was that disciple of Pulatsya, sent a message for Ravana through Vibhisana?

Comment: Can we find this minute detail?  I think it's nearly impossible. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I think we can try referring Valmiki Ramayana or commentaries on Ramayana. I read Valmiki Ramayana but didn't find such details.